# Calculate percentage of each word combination from input

Tags: javascript, regex, math

I'm trying to create something in Javascript that calculates the density percentages of how many times each word or phrase appears within some input. However, all possible combinations need to be calculated within the entire input, and a percentage shown for each combination.

For example, consider the following:

```
input:
green apple pie recipe


output:
"green apple pie recipe" = 100%
"green apple pie" = 75%
"apple pie recipe" = 75%
"green apple" = 50%
"pie recipe" = 50%
"apple pie" = 50%
"green" = 25%
"apple" = 25%
"pie" = 25%
"recipe" = 25%
```

The above is just a simple example, but the script needs to calculate anywhere from a few hundred to a few thousand words. Any ideas?

Comment: Dare i ask - what have you tried??

Comment: This should be fairly simple, are the input words always space delimited?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray So far I haven't tried anything, because honestly I wouldn't even know where to begin.

Comment: @JamesBaxter Yes, for the most part there would only be spaces, with normal things like periods, commas, dashes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok how about something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/8uf8o7zj/

```
var input = "green apple pie recipe";

var sentances = [
    "green apple pie recipe",
    "green apple pie",
    "apple pie recipe",
    "green apple",
    "pie recipe",
    "apple pie",
    "green",
    "apple",
    "pie",
    "recipe"];

var count = input.split(' ').length;
var pattern = input.split(' ').join('|');
var r = new RegExp(pattern,'g');
var output = [];

sentances.forEach(function (sentance) {
    var matches = sentance.match(r);
    output.push({
        'sentance' : sentance,
        'percentage' : (matches) ? (matches.length / count) * 100 : 0,
        toString: function () { return this.sentance + ' - '+ this.percentage + '%' }
    });
});

output.forEach(function (result) {
    alert(result.toString());
});
```

Comment: I think the sentences array should generate from the input string for Tom to get an A+ on his homework

Comment: @JamesBaxter I'm trying to get my head around that - if 4 words you will always get 1x100%, 2x75%, 3x50%, 4x25% - in any event do think this is C or C+ ?